# Size of Drop Down differ in Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, asp.net, css, safari, html-select

In my asp.net web app the size of the drop down list and text box appear same in Chrome but when viewed in the safari browser size of Drop downlist shrinks as compared to size of text box

Here is my html code

```
<div>
    <select
    id="ddlState"
    placeholder="optional"
    class="select"
    title="Select Role">
        <option value="0">state</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div>
    <input
    maxlength="100"
    id="txtCity"
    placeholder="City"
    class="inpt"
    />
</div>
```

and here is my style

```
     .select
{
    width: 224px;
    border: none;
    font: normal 14px/16px "HelveticaNeueLTCom45Light" , Georgia,serif;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 32px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    color: #6d6e71;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
    background: url(../images/selectbg.png) no-repeat right 9px #fff;
}

.inpt{
     border: none;
    font: normal 15px/16px "HelveticaNeueLTCom45Light" , arial,serif;
    margin: 8px 0 15px 0;
    padding: 7px 4px 8px 4px;
    color: #6d6e71;
    width :216px;
}
```

And here is a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7STj4/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7STj4/8/

Set `-webkit-appearance: none;` to select